# How to create an interface for Maps in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to set the types of a Map in Dart, for example, like in typescript you would use interfaces :

```
    interface Record {
        weight: number;
        date: DateTime;
        note: string;
    }
```

so I can use it in a list like this :

```
List<Record> records = [...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in Dart, but you can use classes and do something like this:

```dart
// Create a record class to store its fields
class Record {
    final double weight;
    final DateTime date;
    final String note;

    const Record({this.weight, this.date, this.note});
}

// Populate your list with some records
final List<Record> records = [
    Record(weight: 10.5, date: DateTime(2021, 1, 1), note: "Light"),
    Record(weight: 100.5, date: DateTime(2021, 1, 29), note: "Heavy"),
    Record(weight: 50, date: DateTime(2021, 5, 22), note: "It's ok"),
];

// Access it later
print(records[0].weight);    // 10.5
print(records[0].date);      // DateTime(2021, 1, 1)
print(records[0].note);      // Light

// Access them all
records.forEach((record) {
    print(record.weight);
    print(record.date);
    print(record.note);
});
```